# How to increment list index in a function

Tags: python-3.3

im trying to print the next item in the list by using this function I defined below :

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]

def next():
    i=0
    if (i<4): 
        i= i + 1

    print (List[i])
```

The output of this remains as the second index and doesn't increments no matter how many times i call it

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` in the `next` function is a local variable. It is always initialized to `0` when the function is called.

To make the variable `i` remember the last value, make it as a global variable.

```
i = 0 # <--- global variable

def next():
    global i # <--- declare `i` as a global variable
    if (i<4): 
        i= i + 1

    print (List[i])
```